# How to get correct row count from data view based on distinct values in Two Columns

Tags: vb.net

I have data view in which I need to get row count based on the Combined list of distinct values of two columns(say ColumnA and ColumnB ). I can get the String list of distinct values from these two columns. The part I am struggling with is how to get exact row count (into a List of Integer) from the dataview based on each item in the String list. I think the trouble is some values of ColumnA may not be present in ColumnB and vice versa.If I apply a row filter based on ColumnA , it is possible to miss out on some of the values ColumnB Which is why I did something like below. But I end up getting extra count in the end in my Integer list. If I dont do this then I miss out on some of the values resulting in getting lower combined total than the no. of rows.

Please advise. I need to use the final List of String and Int values to create a basic table and then create a chart in excel.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To DistinctColValueList.Count - 1
    '' OR Condition Below Gives more count
    'Dv.RowFilter = "ColumnA = '" & DistinctColValueList.ElementAt(x) & "' OR ColumnB = '" & DistinctColValueList.ElementAt(x) & "'"

    Dv.RowFilter = "ColumnA = '" & DistinctColValueList.ElementAt(x) & "'"

    DistinctIntValueList.Add(Dv.Count)
Next

Dim ClonedList As New List(Of Integer)
For Each item In DistinctIntValueList
    ClonedList.Add(item)
Next

Dv.RowFilter = ""
DistinctIntValueList.Clear()

For y As Integer = 0 To DistinctColValueList.Count - 1
    Dv.RowFilter = "ColumnB = '" & DistinctColValueList.ElementAt(y) & "'"

    Dim Abs_Diff = Math.Abs(ClonedList.ElementAt(y) - Dv.Count)

    DistinctIntValueList.Add(ClonedList.ElementAt(y) + Abs_Diff)
Next
```

Update: added example table.

```
+-----------------------------+
|Item    |Column_A  |Column B |
|        |          |         |
+-----------------------------+
| XYZ1   |   Loc1   |  Loc5   |
| XYZ2   |   Loc13  |  Loc6   |
| XYZ3   |   Loc4   |  Loc4   |
| XYZ4   |   Loc6   |  Loc10  |
| XYZ5   |   Loc5   |  Loc2   |
| XYZ6   |   Loc5   |  Loc6   |
| XYZ7   |   Loc6   |  Loc9   |
| XYZ8   |   Loc4   |  Loc10  |
| XYZ9   |   Loc6   |  Loc13  |
| XYZ10  |   Loc2   |  Loc10  |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly how do you get the distinct values, but I would add a new calculated column (See DataColumn.Expression) that is the concatenation of the first with the second column. At that point the distinct works on the calculated column

Comment: @Steve I don't think that's what the OP wants. Assume the following set `{{steve, steve} , {steve, jon}, {dave, steve}}` I believe the OP wants `{{steve,3}, {jon, 1}, {dave,1}}` Concatenation won't help getting there. A union of the two columns would do it though e.g `dv.Select(ColA).Union(dv.Select(ColB)`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have added a sample table image in original post. As you can see some values in Column_A may not be present in column_B. I used http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/153008/Select-DISTINCT-records-based-on-specified-fields to get list of distinct values from two columns. Now that I have List of String(of these distinct values), I need to apply those as filter against the table above to get row count for each value. Now a value from col_A can be repeated in Col_B or vice versa. I hope this is more clear..

Comment: Conrad, I tried your method but i got more overall count of rows. that's the bit I am struggling..

Comment: @DK2014 Union won't work since it does a distinct. You need to use concat see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem is concat the values in Column A and Column B where A<>B and then Concat where they are the same and do the counts.

Using the DataTable provided I wrote the following. It also has the advantage of getting the distinct values and the counts at once

```
Dim dt As New DataTable("Test")
dt.Columns.Add("Item", "".[GetType]())
dt.Columns.Add("Column_A", "".[GetType]())
dt.Columns.Add("Column_B", "".[GetType]())

dt.Rows.Add("XYZ1", "Loc1", "Loc5")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ2", "Loc13", "Loc6")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ3", "Loc4", "Loc4")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ4", "Loc6", "Loc10")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ5", "Loc5", "Loc2")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ6", "Loc5", "Loc6")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ7", "Loc6", "Loc9")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ8", "Loc4", "Loc10")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ9", "Loc6", "Loc13")
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ10", "Loc2", "Loc10")


'get a collection where A <> B
Dim diff = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Column_A") <> x.Field(Of String)("Column_B"))

'get a concat of A and B where A<>B and concat where A=B
Dim concat = diff.[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Column_A")) _
            .Concat(diff.[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Column_B"))) _
            .Concat(dt.AsEnumerable() _
            .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Column_A") = x.Field(Of String)("Column_B")) _
              .[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Column_A")))

'Group by to get the counts
Dim result = concat.GroupBy(Function(value) value).[Select](Function(group) New With { _
    Key .Value = group.Key, _
    Key .Count = group.Count() _
})
Console.WriteLine("Value | Count")
For Each x In result
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", x.Value, x.Count)
Next
```

Results

```
Value | Count
Loc1 | 1
Loc13 | 2
Loc6 | 5
Loc5 | 3
Loc4 | 2
Loc2 | 2
Loc10 | 3
Loc9 | 1
```

Comment: Thanks Conrad. your help is much appreciated,,is there anyway i can send u actual table?

Comment: I'd rather you explained why my answer isn't helping you. That way I can improve my answer and hopefully better help someone who is trying the same thing as you.

Comment: I think your answer has given me right direction. I am not sure if I can posta larger table here? but will try. Its about 120 rows. That way I am be sure that I am not doing anything wrong..

Comment: I think I have now understood how it works. Although you may have 10 rows but the values in columnA and B may be repeated so you will get the overall count higher than actual rows. This is correct as actually it tell you how many of columnA or B value exists in the table giving you an overall figure. The positive of this is if an Item is in table B and not in A or vice versa, it won't get unnoticed. And that was my main intention. Many thanks Conrad..